# Error says "object is null" if one the object's properties is null

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a slight problem in Javascript with objects being handled in a strange (to say the least) way, unless I'm missing something.

I have an object named `state`. When I do `console.log(state)` I get this:

[image: see image please]

At this point, I try to go through the object using jQuery's `each`:

```
$.each(state, function (i, sobj) {
        if(mid == sobj.user_id)
            //some stuff;
    });
```

However, here I get an error saying `TypeError: sobj is null`. I found that this is because the `trump` property within the object (see image above) is initialized to `null`. With any other value, it works. Obviously I can fix this by initializing it to 0 or something, but this is bugging me on a conceptual level: why shouldn't one of the properties be allowed to have `null` as its value? It doesn't make sense to me that I should get an error saying the whole object is null when I loop through it like this, just because one of the properties is null. I didn't try to do anything with the property specifically.

So, can someone tell me why this is happening (Google doesn't help) and if there's a way to fix it besides the obvious "don't let anything be null within an object"?

Comment: "why shouldn't one of the properties be allowed to have null as its value?" Well, properties *are* allowed to have null as a value. But if one of the properties has a null value then you *aren't* allowed to get its `user_id` (because `null` doesn't have a `user_id`)

Comment: In my opinion, your `state` object should have a new `seats` property which contains an array of `user` objects. Then you can iterate just over those rather than having to iterate *all* the state properties

Comment: Would that save time performance-wise or is it just a case of "best practice"?

Comment: Well the answer you've accepted at the moment will fail if any other property has an object as its value. Things aren't "best practise" just because they're optional, they're "best practise" because they are simple ways avoid things which can break easily

Comment: Ok, thanks. Either way, I'll make sure it's not null (which is easy enough in my application).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you only want to iterate over the objects inside the `state` object. You could check if the item is an object.

```
$.each(state, function (i, sobj) {
    if(typeof(sobj) == "object" && mid == sobj.user_id)
        //some stuff;
});
```

Comment: I really only need `seat` and `user_id` of 1, 2, 3 and 4 in the loop, the rest of the object comes into play later.

Answer (score 1):

You're iterating over the entire object like it's a collection of objects - meaning that trump in this case is an object, not a property of an object(state).  You either need to iterate only over the collection of objects in state, or test that the object isn't null before you look for a property value:

```
if(typeof(sobj) != 'undefined'){
    if(mid == sobj.user_id)
            //some stuff;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this approach will work, because it will iterate over the non-object attributes of the `sate` object.

Comment: Sergio - the example will work, it's meant to execute inside the foreach loop, not as a replacement for it.